# Closing dollar is sometimes not recognized when the math snippet contains a less-than sign

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax

There is a strange interaction between Markdown and MathJax when the character `<` appears in a math snippet which is followed by some (not all) non-whitespace character. I would have expected `<` not to have any special meaning between `$` signs and the character after the closing `$` not to matter, but this is not always the case.

```
I say “then $a<b$”. More $math$.

I say “then $a<b$”. *Emphasis* $math$.
```

> I say “then $a
>
> I say “then $aEmphasis $math$.

[image: screenshot from <code>https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask</code>]

I observed this in Chrome 17.0.963.79. Initially while composing [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/772/error-in-the-use-of-asymptotic-notation/784#784), and the screeenshot above is from https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask (my screenshot-grabbing extension sometimes puts the wrong URL).

Comment: Can confirm for Firefox 10.0.2.

Comment: A workaround is to use \lt and \gt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should be encoded as `\lt` and `\gt` instead of using `<` and `>` directly.